# Linux bash scripting - Grouping of commands

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm a newbie in bash scripting and I have a problem with the aggrupation of the commands. Precisely in this line of code:

```
timeout -s 9 1 echo $var | nc localhost port
```

I'm trying to send data of a variable var via netcat to localhost in a specific port, and I want to timeout that command for 1 second. Reading the man pages of timeout I understand that it should be used as:

```
timeout -s SIGNAL TIME COMMAND
```

My question is how to replace COMMAND with the piped command echo $var | nc localhost port and for further knowledge how to write correctly the next situations:

```
COMMAND1 | (COMMAND2 | COMMAND3)
```

and

```
(COMMAND1 | COMMAND2) | COMMAND3
```

If I'm correct, the second example is equivalent to

```
COMMAND1 | COMMAND2 | COMMAND3
```

but I don't know how to write the first one.

Comment: You could just do `echo "$var" | timeout -s 9 1 nc localhost port`  That wouldn't solve the overall issue of timing out an entire pipeline though.

Comment: @jesse_b yeah I like this aproach, thank you so much!!

Comment: Do you mean aggregation (or grouping)?

Comment: For this particular case **you don't need a pipeline:** `timeout -s9 1 nc localhost port <<<$var` (unless it contains globs you want expanded, or whitespace to be normalized)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that's a pretty elegant solution, I didn't know about the <<< operator, thank you for the new knowledge!!

Comment: @muru What is the difference between aggregation and grouping? Edit: I meant grouping but didn't remember exactly the english word, sorry!! With the general problem I meant what could be an abstract solution for pipelining a command COM1 to the result of COM2 | COM3; if I'm not wrong a posible solution could be COM1 | bash -c "COM2 | COM3" using the schematic of the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That COMMAND is going to be interpreted by `timeout`, not `bash`. You cannot put a subshell (the piped commands inside `(` and `)`).

You could put your commands inside a shell script and then pass its name to `timeout`.

Or actually force COMMAND to be interpreted by `bash`. This should work:

```
timeout -s 9 1 bash -c "echo $var | nc localhost port"
```

Comment: This was the main issue, I thought that the COMMAND was interpreted directly by bash, now I see clearly why it didn't work. Thank you!!